# Dumping full file/folder permissions report for access permission auditing in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace

We have Google Drive folders and team/shared drives with thousands of files and folders. Over the years they have been shared by numerous folks and thousands of folks have access to differnent files/folders at different levels.

I'm trying to find a way to dump every file/folder from a source folder along with what the permissions are for that file/folder. So, something that has a detailed report of every file/folder with permissions applied to it.

This would let someone review and see exactly who has access to what so they can make a decision on if the access needs to be removed.

For example, imagine a file/folder structure like this:

- Folder A - **user1**, **user2**

  - Folder A.A

    - File A.A.1 - **user3**
  - Folder A.B
  - Folder A.C - **group1**
- Folder C - **group3**

  - Folder C.A
  - Folder C.B - **group4**

    - File C.B.1 - **user1**
    - File C.B.2 - **user2**
  - File C.1
  - File C.2

A permission report for this would look like:

| Item Type | Item Path | Permission Application | Permission Grant |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| folder | `Folder A` | direct | **user1** |
| folder | `Folder A` | direct | **user2** |
| folder | `Folder A` > `Folder A.A` | inherited | **user1** |
| folder | `Folder A` > `Folder A.A` | inherited | **user2** |
| file | `Folder A` > `Folder A.A` > `File A.A.1` | inherited | **user1** |
| file | `Folder A` > `Folder A.A` > `File A.A.1` | inherited | **user2** |
| file | `Folder A` > `Folder A.A` > `File A.A.1` | direct | **user3** |
| folder | `Folder A` > `Folder A.B` | inherited | **user1** |
| folder | `Folder A` > `Folder A.B` | inherited | **user2** |
| folder | `Folder A` > `Folder A.C` | inherited | **user1** |
| folder | `Folder A` > `Folder A.C` | inherited | **user2** |
| folder | `Folder A` > `Folder A.C` | direct | **group1** |
| folder | `Folder C` | direct | **group3** |
| folder | `Folder C` > `Folder C.A` | inherited | **group3** |
| folder | `Folder C` > `Folder C.B` | inherited | **group3** |
| folder | `Folder C` > `Folder C.B` | direct | **group4** |
| file | `Folder C` > `Folder C.B` > `File C.B.1` | inherited | **group3** |
| file | `Folder C` > `Folder C.B` > `File C.B.1` | inherited | **group4** |
| file | `Folder C` > `Folder C.B` > `File C.B.1` | direct | **user1** |
| file | `Folder C` > `Folder C.B` > `File C.B.2` | inherited | **group3** |
| file | `Folder C` > `Folder C.B` > `File C.B.2` | inherited | **group4** |
| file | `Folder C` > `Folder C.B` > `File C.B.2` | direct | **user2** |
| file | `Folder C` > `File C.1` | inherited | **group3** |
| file | `Folder C` > `File C.2` | inherited | **group3** |

When you have tens of thousands of files and folders, it may not be obvious that **group4** has access to `Folder C` > `Folder C.B` > `File C.B.2`. Maybe **group4** should not have access to `File C.B.2`. If you have a report like above then you can see that **group4** has access to `File C.B.2` and so you know you need to remove it.

My current thought is to:

1. Use Drive API drive.files.list (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) to dump a list of files/folders from some root folder
2. Use Google's batch request API (https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/batch) to make batched calls to drive.permissions.list (https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/batch)

But this seems horribly inefficient -- especially if there are tens of thousands of files/folders.

Answer (score 1):

Check out GAMADV-XTD3 - command line tool for Google Workspace administration
https://github.com/taers232c/GAMADV-XTD3

It has plenty of scripts, as per your requirements I would check `GetTeamDriveFileACLs.py` and `GetSharedFiles.py` but there are additional scripts that will give you insights about the permissions on personal and shred team drives.
https://github.com/taers232c/GAM-Scripts3